# NMEAListener not working?

Tags: android, gps, listener, nmea

I was testing an app using `NMEAListener`, and noticed that I need to call `LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates` to get it receiving strings. So to use `NMEAListener` I need to register the regular Location listener first. I didn't find anywhere in the docs that this should be done that way. If I register only the NMEAListener, no string is received (and the GPS icon in the top system bar is never shown). Seems that the GPS is not turned on by this listener.

Do you think this is a bug?

NOTE: I'm using 2.3 Gingerbread.

---

UPDATE
These issues might be related:
[Issue 7321](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7321)
[Issue 15500](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15500)

Answer (score 0):

NmeaListener (long depricated by 2019) seems only to be a byproduct of requesting GPS Provider Location Updates. If you LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates using NETWORK_PROVIDER you will also not receive nmea sentences.

I think the GPS chip dishes out only NMEA sentences and the android system is converting that into Location class data and pushes it out quite uncomputed to the NmeaListener. The other way around is just not available: using GSM/WLAN data to compute lat/lon and then convert into "fake" NMEA sentences isn't done.